# why I still have warning: Expected to return a value at the end of async arrow function in cloud function, even though I have returned a promise?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new in NodeJS and Firebase cloud function, here is my code in my firebase cloud function:

```
exports.dbModeratorsOnCreate = functions.firestore.document('moderators/{moderatorID}').onUpdate(async (change,context) => {

    // grant custom claim to the newly created moderator

    try {

        const moderatorID = context.params.moderatorID

        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(moderatorID, {
            moderator: true
        })

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

})
```

as you can see, I have returned a promise in `return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(moderatorID` , but why when I deploy using `firebase deploy` i still have warning in the terminal that said

> warning : Expected to return a value at the end of async arrow
>   function  consistent-return

Comment: What do you expect to be returned if there is an exception caught in your `catch` block?  The error message is suggesting that you need a return value in every code path.

Comment: @DougStevenson is it possible to do nothing ? I mean, I just want log the error, and I can notice the error in the cloud function console. what should I do if it is possible to remove the warning ?

Comment: If you wan to do nothing, then return null.  The point is to explicitly tell TypeScript that you've though about all code paths, so that no matter what happens, the result is expected and not arbitrary or accidental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing return value outside try catch block, in case there's exception there's no return from the function, modify the function as follows

```
exports.dbModeratorsOnCreate = functions.firestore.document('moderators/{moderatorID}').onUpdate(async (change,context) => {

    // grant custom claim to the newly created moderator

    try {

        const moderatorID = context.params.moderatorID

        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(moderatorID, {
            moderator: true
        })

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    return null
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The linter is informing you that there is a way for your code to run that doesn't return a value. In your code above, this is because no value is returned when your `try`-`catch` block catches an exception.

However, with the code as it is above, the `try`-`catch` block won't do anything useful because the only two errors that would trigger it would be not initialising the Admin SDK or some syntax error.

To catch the errors from the `setCustomUserClaims` operation using a `try`-`catch` block, you must make use of `await`. Also, as [`setCustomUserClaims`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#setcustomuserclaims) doesn't resolve to a value, there is no need to return it when used this way.

Also, your current code doesn't handle the case where a moderator is deleted and their permission should be revoked. This can be added by changing to `onWrite` instead of `onUpdate` (which should have been `onCreate`) and checking the value of `change.after.exists`. If we add this functionality, it also makes sense to rename the function to `dbModeratorsUpdateClaims` or similar.

```js
exports.dbModeratorsUpdateClaims = functions.firestore.document('moderators/{moderatorID}').onWrite(async (change,context) => { // <-- changed to onWrite

    // grants/revokes custom claim of the related moderator

    try {

        const moderatorID = context.params.moderatorID        
        const isModerator = change.after.exists // if deleted, revokes permission

        await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(moderatorID, { // <-- added await
            moderator: hasModeratorPermissions
        });

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Alternatively, not using the `async`/`await` syntax, you can return the promise itself and chain to it's rejection handler.

```
exports.dbModeratorsUpdateClaims = functions.firestore.document('moderators/{moderatorID}').onWrite((change,context) => { // <-- changed to onWrite

    // grants/revokes custom claim of the related moderator

    const moderatorID = context.params.moderatorID
    const isModerator = change.after.exists // if deleted, revokes permission

    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(moderatorID, {
        moderator: isModerator
    })
    .catch((error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
})
```